# Pandas groupby on two columns not giving a proper data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
+----------------+--+
|    class  name |  |
+----------------+--+
| 0     A    a1  |  |
| 1     A    a2  |  |
| 2     A    a3  |  |
| 3     A    a1  |  |
| 4     B    b2  |  |
| 5     C    c1  |  |
|                |  |
+----------------+--+
```

I was trying to get the count of the 'name' column with respect to the class. I was using the groupby function for this purpose.This is the new dataframe I am looking for:

```
+---------------------+--+
| class name    Count |  |
+---------------------+--+
| A      a1      2    |  |
| A      a2      1    |  |
| A      a3      1    |  |
| B      b2      1    |  |
| C      c1      1    |  |
|                     |  |
+---------------------+--+
```

I used the following line of code:

```
mydf.groupby(['class','name'])['name'].count()
and got the following result:

+------------------+--+
|   class  name    |  |
+------------------+--+
| A      a1      2 |  |
|        a2      1 |  |
|        a3      1 |  |
| B      b2      1 |  |
| C      c1      1 |  |
|                  |  |
+------------------+--+
```

Is there any way I can fix the 'class' column? I know there are enough questions out there to convert groupby objects to a dataframe. I couldn't find a solution to this issue. Is there an easier way to do this?

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This shows you where the rows have the same class in the grouped index, if you want the class values to repeat then call `reset_index()` to restored the grouped index values back as a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name='count'`:

```
print mydf.groupby(['class','name'])['name'].count().reset_index(name='count')
  class name  count
0     A   a1      2
1     A   a2      1
2     A   a3      1
3     B   b2      1
4     C   c1      1
```

But aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) is better:

```
print mydf.groupby(['class', 'name']).size().reset_index(name='count')
  class name  count
0     A   a1      2
1     A   a2      1
2     A   a3      1
3     B   b2      1
4     C   c1      1
```